# Smearing Phenomenon in GDI+ After a Window is Dragged Over the UserControl

Tags: c#, gdi+

I am creating a UserControl, and I wanted to add a border to it via `ControlPaint.DrawBorder()`.
I created an override for `OnPaint()`, and put this in it:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);


    int     Border_Width    =1;
    Color   Border_Color    =Color.FromArgb(170,170,170);

    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics,e.ClipRectangle,
        Border_Color,Border_Width,ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,      //Left
        Border_Color,Border_Width,ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,      //Top
        Border_Color,Border_Width,ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,      //Right
        Border_Color,Border_Width,ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);     //Bottom
}
```

The border is drawn well, but since I added that, a problem has started:

Whenever I drag some other window over that user control, I get a "leftover" smearing on the user control..

See how it looks:

**Before overriding OnPaint():**

[image]

**After overriding OnPaint():**

[image]

Why does this happen?

From my experiments,
Trying to enable DubbleBuffering did not help here.. The smearing remained..

Also, If I disable the `ControlPaint.DrawBorder()` line,
and replace it with `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle()`,
then the problem disappears..

So it means the problem is not necessarily in overriding `OnPaint()` or something like that, but with `ControlPaint.DrawBorder()`.

Is the `ControlPaint` class problematic in other drawing operations that it provides?
Is there a fix for that, or maybe it should be avoided due to this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you use the cliprect to draw the border, that means only the part of the control that should be redrawn. Use the control dimensions/coordinates to draw the border.

Comment: According to your suggestion I changed now the second parameter from `e.ClipRectangle` to `this.Bounds`, and surprisingly it seems that the problem is solved.. But I don't understand why.. Do you know why? This parameter should affect the Location and Size of the rectangle of the border, how can it affect the smearing phenomenon described above?

Comment: As i've mentioned above the cliprect is the part of the control, that should be redrawn. DrawBorder only draws a border around the Rectangle parameter and doesn't take into accout the bounds of the control itself. If you use ClipRectangle you only "mark" ie. draw a border around the changed ClipRect region. Because this "marks" are never overdrawn the smearing effect arises.

Hmmm ...

Take your original "smearing" code, place the DrawRectangle() statement you've mentioned just before your DrwarBorder() Statement and observe the behaviour ...

I'm sure you then can understand the behavior!

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the role of `e.ClipRectangle`.  It is not related to your window content, it only tells you what part of your window needs to be repainted.  The bug in your code is highly visible only on XP, much less on newer Windows versions that use Aero.

When you drag another window across yours, the OS tells you that you need to repaint only the part of your window that is revealed by the move.  Just a sliver, if you drag horizontally then it will be only as wide as the amount by which the user moved the window since the last time you painted.  `e.ClipRectangle` contains that sliver.

It is intended to help you optimize your painting code.  Since you only have to draw that sliver, you can skip any code that draws outside of it.  Optimizing your painting code can be important, if it is too slow then the user can see the unpainted part of the sliver and that produces a visual effect that resembles what you see when you enable mouse trails.  Windows itself is however already optimized to observe ClipRectangle internally.  You still make the Graphics method calls but they don't do anything.  Or do only part of the job you asked them to do, the part that intersects with ClipRectangle.  So it is pretty rare to actually have to write that code and test against the rectangle.

Your bug is much less visible on Aero, it double-buffers the window surface in memory.  Closer to the way many programmers think that painting should work.  It can very quickly repaint the sliver from the surface copy without asking you to help.  It however still occurs when you drag the window off the screen and back, the double-buffered surface does not include the part of the window that is not on the screen.